# SHGetValueW returns different value for x64 and x86

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I am using SHGetValueW API to read a registry value.

```
WCHAR activePolicyCode[512UL] = { 0 };
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(activePolicyCode);
DWORD type;    

LSTATUS ret = SHGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\DeviceAccess", L"ActivePolicyCode", &type, &activePolicyCode, &dwSize);
```

For x64, it's returning 0 - ERROR_SUCCESS

But for x86, it's returning 2 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Why is the difference in behavior? How to read the value from x86 application?

Comment: Look up registry redirection, and consider using the registry API which will allow you to access the 64 bit view of the registry from a 32 bit process.

Comment: There are two different registries

Comment: There are not two different registries. Some keys are redirected and have 32 and 64 bit views that are distinct.

Comment: See [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/Registry-redirector), and in particular [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) and [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The abstraction is that there are two different registries.  The implementation is that one of them is stored inside a "WOW64Node" branch of the other one.

Comment: @BenVoigt My point is that the abstraction only applies to a subset of the registry. For instance, it doesn't apply in HKCU

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It doesn't apply to all of HKCU, but it does apply "in" HKCU.  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` exists and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node` is decently full, at least on my workstation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 32-bit applications running on 64-bit systems, registry functions are redirected to `WOW6432Node`.
So if you query `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hKey, you will actually get values from:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node
```

So in your case, this key probably does not exists in WOW6432Node.
You can use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in `RegOpenKeyExW`:

```
HKEY hKey=0;
DWORD dwType=0;
BYTE pbData[1024];
DWORD dwDataSize = sizeof(pbData);

LSTATUS lStatus = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\DeviceAccess", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);

if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
   
    lStatus = SHGetValueW(hKey, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\DeviceAccess", L"ActivePolicyCode", &dwType, pbData, &dwDataSize);

    // Close the registry key
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
 
}
```

More info about accessing [alternate registry views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view):